# Does Java actually do something with empty statements?

Tags: java, jvm

The official docs just say

> 14.6. The Empty Statement
>
> An empty statement does nothing.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6)

Are statements like `;;;;;;;;;;;` actually compiled by the Java compiler?
If so, do these statements take time to be executed, like a `nop`?
In short: does an empty statement really do "nothing"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The java compiler does nothing with these statements. Hence, they are ignored. 
The following method

```
public static void test(){
  ;;;;;;;;
}
```

just compiles to the following Bytecode:

```
public static void test();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=0, locals=0, args_size=0
     0: return
  LineNumberTable:
    line 39: 0
```

Compilers just use NOPs in certain compilation strategies.